# Оптимизация VS2019 под С/С++

Tags: c++

Изучаю алгоритмы сортировки на С++. До этого прогнал все алгоритмы на C#. Есть сгенерированные тестовые файлы со строками по 50 Гб. Длина строки не превышает 250 символов.
Пишу в Visual Studio 2019. Windows 10.
Написал программу для чтения файла с диска. Программа читает строки line by line и выводит количество строки и время за которое выполнено чтение. C# читает файл со скоростью 155-160 мб/сек, если смотреть по монитору ресурсов.

```
string file = "....testFile....";
long count = 0;

ifstream input(file);

for (std::string line; getline(input, line); )
{
    count++;
}

cout << count << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

В режиме debug и без оптимизации скорость 2 мб/сек.
В режиме release c флагом -О2 скорость 40-45 мб/сек.
Ок. скорость маленькая. Переписал вот так:

```
char const* const fileName = "....testFile...."; 
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
char line[256];

long count = 0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
{
    count++;       
}

printf("%ld",count);
fclose(file);   

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Скорость примерно 95-98 мб/сек. в режиме Release и флагом -О2
Тоже не дотягивает до C#.
Далее использовал код с fget c компилятором. g++ также с флагом -О2.
скорость 130-135 мб/сек.

Код на C#:

```
        string inFile = @"....testFile....";
        
        long count = 0;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inFile);
        string line;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{count}");
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Done. elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Читал много вопросов на аналогичные темы, но ответ на них в основном отправляет в сторону Linux c кодом типа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "/media/sf_Share_Folder/CPP/10.2.txt";

    FILE* ifile = fopen("test file","r");
    size_t linesSize = 4096+1;
    char* line = new char[linesSize];
    unsigned int i=0;
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    while (getline(&line,&linesSize,ifile)>0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    auto finish = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto elapsed_ms = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(finish - start);

    cout << dec << elapsed_ms.count() << endl;

    delete[] line;

    cout<<"Lines count: "<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

И далее разъяснения на тему отличий getline. Этот код у меня под VirtualBox c Ubuntu 20.04 и QT creator c  компилятором GCC без всякой оптимизации выдаёт 60мб/сек. Думаю при установке на физическую машину выдаст все 150 мб/сек, но я не проверял.

Вопрос мой вот в чем. Можно ли как-то оптимизировать код под VS2019 чтобы примерно подтянуть его к показателям по скорости чтения как у C# то есть 150 мб/сек?

**Update:** Установил QT creator 6.0.1 c mingw81_64 на этот же ПК. скорость считывания с fgets  145-150 мбит/сек.

Comment: `char line[256]; ...` Сразу уточните (в вопросе), строки в вашем файле фиксированной длины или произвольной. Если произвольной, то есть ли ограничение на максимальную длину (или хоть весь файл — одна строка)

Comment: @wololo максимальная длина не превышает 250 символов

Comment: `setvbuf` не пробовали?

Comment: @Harry нет не пробовал ещё. какой лучше LBF или FBF?

Comment: Заявленная проблема не воспроизводится. Может у вас там антивирус свирепствует или еще что-то?

Comment: @Harry setvbuf _IOLBF -> те же 90-92 мб/сек.

Comment: @user7860670 У вас на Win 10 c VS2019 c++ читает файл также быстро как и c#?

Comment: Какая кодировка у текстовых файлов?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov UTF-8

Comment: @Deim а можете попробовать провести на "плохой конфигурации" тест, но только вместо getline/gets использовать обычный fread и буфер попробовать как 256, так и в районе 8к? (да, я понимаю, будут читаться не строки, а куски, но тут понять, какая с половин тормозит - подсистема ввода или плюсовая обвязка). Я когда то на это тоже натыкался (мне нужно было логи быстро парсить) и закончилось тем, что читал кусками по пару мегабайт и дробил в памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim провёл тест. изложил результат в Update2. В этом тесте проект запущенный под QT creator показывает такие же результаты как и на VS2019

Comment: вот вот. при 8кб скорость максимальна, потому что это "достаточно оптимальный размер буфера". И, что самое приятное, ещё и сильно быстрее дотнета получается. Осталось дописать десяток строк и получить хороший быстрый код.

Comment: Напишите ответ. Переместите в него ваш Update2.

Comment: А вы укажите дотнету в конструкторе `StreamReader` кодировку `Encoding.ASCII`, чтобы было более честное сравнение. C++ ведь не интерпретирует байты.

Comment: @KoVadim вы не разбирались в причинах такого поведения кода под VS?

Comment: Пытался. Похоже, что внутри майкрософтовской реализации слишком много проверок и преобразований (например, локаль). Но это нужно исследовать отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующий код на VS2019 даже без оптимизации и в режиме Debug выдаёт скорость чтения в ~240 Мб/сек. В режиме Release - O2 скорость стабильно 350-355 Мб/сек. При размере буфера 256 - скорость 340 Мб/сек. при размере буфера 8196 байт показывает максимальную указанную выше скорость.

```
char const* const fileName = "... test file ...";
char* buffer[8196];
FILE* file_ = fopen(fileName, "r");

auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

while (!feof(file_))
{
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file_);
}       

auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();   

auto elapsed_ms = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);

cout << "Elapsed ms: " << elapsed_ms.count() << endl;
```